# web api jquery ajax request cannot parse Json data

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, asp.net-web-api

I make a jquery ajax request to retrieve the data from a MVC Web API. The error says

Json parse error. No conversion from text to object

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/api/StatusMessage",
        dataType: JSON,
        error: ajaxError,
        success: displayData
    });
```

The web API output the following data. They're in Json format so I don't understand why the conversion fails...

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "bla bla"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "bla bla"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "bla bla"
  }
]
```

The controller

```
 public class StatusMessageController : ApiController
    {
        public IStatusMessage repo = new StatusMessageRepository();

        public List<StatusMessage> GetAllStatusMessage()
        {
             return repo.GetAll().ToList();
        }

    }
```

Comment: What is occurring in the function displayData? Is it getting that far?

Comment: nope. i put an alert in the displayData. the alert doesn't even appear -_-"

Comment: We need more code here. The rest of your AJAX code and also your Controller code if possible.

Comment: You should probably quote the dataType, as it is it's a syntax error.